# Get all components with a specific interface in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

some `GameObjects` in my scene implement the interace `ISaveable`. In my script, I want to find all these interfaces and store them. Later on I can loop through them and call their implemented method `SaveData()`.

My current workaround to find these interfaces:

```
    List<ISaveable> saveables = new List<ISaveable>();
    MonoBehaviour[] sceneObjects = FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < sceneObjects.Length; i++)
    {
        MonoBehaviour currentObj = sceneObjects[i];
        ISaveable currentComponent = currentObj.GetComponent<ISaveable>();

        if (currentComponent != null)
        {
            saveables.Add(currentComponent);
        }
    }
```

The code works fine but is there a better way? I don't want to search for each Monobehaviour in the scene and then try to get its interface component.

Answer (score 13):

#### Simplified filter using Linq

You can use [Linq `OfType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype)

```
ISaveable[] saveables = FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>(true).OfType<ISaveable>().ToArray();
```

of course it still requires to find all objects first.

Note though that it underlies the general limitations of `FindObjectsOfType` regarding inactive GameObjects or disabled behaviors. (UPDATE: In newer Unity versions the optional `bool` parameter enables to include inactive/disabled components as well.)

Also see [`Object.FindObjectsByType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsByType.html) nowadays (which still is limited to `UnityEngine.Object`)

---

#### Iterate through the Hierachy

You could extend it to go through all root level objects of the scene. This works since `GetComponentsInChildren` indeed **does** work also with interfaces!

```
var saveables = new List<ISaveable>();
var rootObjs = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().GetRootGameObjects();
foreach(var root in rootObjs)
{
    // Pass in "true" to include inactive and disabled children
    saveables.AddRange(root.GetComponentsInChildren<ISaveable>(true));
}
```

If it's more efficient - yes, no, maybe, I don't know - but it includes also inactive and disabled objects.

And yes one could extend that to iterate through multiple loaded scenes using

```
var saveables = new List<ISaveable>();
for(var i = 0; i < SceneManager.sceneCount; i++)
{
    var rootObjs = SceneManager.GetSceneAt(i).GetRootGameObjects();
    foreach(var root in rootObjs)
    {
        saveables.AddRange(root.GetComponentsInChildren<ISaveable>(true));
    }
}
```

---

#### Not use an interface in the first place

This alternative is a bit similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49330090/7111561) but it has a huge flaw: You would need a specific implementation for the interface in order to make it work which invalidates the whole idea of an interface.

So the big question also from the comments there is: **Why have an interface at all?**

If it is anyway only going to be used for `MonoBehaviour` you should rather have an `abstract class` like

```
public abstract class SaveableBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Inheritors have to implement this (just like with an interface)
    public abstract void SaveData();
}
```

This already solves the entire issue with using `FindObjectsOfType` anyway since now you could simply use

```
SaveableBehaviour[] saveables = FindObjectsOfType<SaveableBehaviour>();
```

but you can still go further: For even easier and more efficient access you can make them register themselves completely without the need of a manager or Singleton pattern! Why should a the type not simply handle its instances itself?

```
public abstract class SaveableBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Inheritors have to implement this (just like with an interface)
    public abstract void SaveData();

    private static readonly HashSet<SaveableBehaviour> instances = new HashSet<SaveableBehaviour>();

    // public read-only access to the instances by only providing a clone
    // of the HashSet so nobody can remove items from the outside
    public static HashSet<SaveableBehaviour> Instances => new HashSet<SaveableBehaviour>(instances);

    protected virtual void Awake()
    {
        // simply register yourself to the existing instances
        instances.Add(this);
    }

    protected virtual void OnDestroy()
    {
        // don't forget to also remove yourself at the end of your lifetime
        instances.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

so you can then simply inherit

```
public class Example : SaveableBehaviour
{
    public override void SaveData()
    {
       // ...
    }

    protected override void Awake()
    {
        base.Awake(); // Make sure to always keep that line

        // do additional stuff
    }
}
```

and you could access all instances of that type via

```
HashSet<SaveableBehaviour> saveables = SaveableBehaviour.Instances;
foreach(var saveable in saveables)
{
    saveable.SaveData();
}
```

Comment: Good call !  I think GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>() seems more natural than starting with  GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Transform>() ..

Comment: The first solution is not much different from the one provided in the question. Maybe slightly prettier. But if part of the concern is about the efficiency of searching the whole scene, storing it, then filtering the output, well, this code does the same thing. The second solution is possibly an alternative - but possibly not, because we don't know why an interface is being used in the first place. Can you avoid it? Maybe yes, maybe no, depending on the circumstance.

Comment: @Joseph But what you do in your answer is the same thing as my second suggestion so what is the downvote for? The concerns you mentioned I even mentioned in the answer anyway

Comment: There is no way, whatsoever, to search a scene other than .................. searching a scene :)  Such questions are inherently about idiom, fine points of efficiency, and dealing with the inevitably issue in game engines of the obviously highly dynamic nature of what the hell is in a scene (particularly the nuisance of how that will change inter-frame due to script execution order).

Comment: "Why have an interface at all?".. Because C# does not support multiple inheritance and those monobehavious are already inheriting from classes

Comment: @JohnStock the argument was: Why instead of inherit from `MonoBehaviour` not directly inherit from a common abstract class ... I know how c# works ;) It depends on the exact use case of course => `If it is anyway only going to be used for MonoBehaviour` is how I started that sentence ;)

Answer (score 4):

You could have a manager class holding a collection/list of `ISaveable`.

You can then make that manager class a singleton by setting the Singleton value in its Awake method.

```
class SaveManager(){
public static SaveManager Instance;
Awake(){
if (Instance == null)
   {
    Instance = this;
   }
}

List<ISaveable> SaveAbles;
public void AddSaveAble(ISaveAble saveAble){
//add it to the list.
}
}
```

Then in the Start method of class implementing the `ISaveable` interface you can use the Singleton to add it to the total list.

```
class Example : MonoBehaviour, ISaveable
{
void Start(){
SaveManager.Instance.AddSaveAble(this);
}
}
```

That way, each SaveAble adds itself to the manager via the managers method when it is created.

Note that it is important that the Singleton is set in Awake so it can be used in Start, as Awake comes first in the lifecycle.

Comment: If you go with this method, you'd also want to make sure you remove from the collection with an `OnDestroy()` implementation.  For that reason, I'd switch the `List` to a `HashSet` for O(1) removal time.

Comment: Also, that `Awake()` function wont be called unless `SaveManager` implements `MonoBehaviour` and exists somewhere in the heirarchy.  For that reason, you wouldn't want a singleton pattern, just a `MonoBehaviour` implementation with a call to `DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject)` (if you want it to persist across scenes).

Comment: On top of that, you're making the implication that your interface has to be implemented in a specific manner (which defeats the purpose of an interface).  This would work better as an abstract base class that extends `MonoBehaviour` and guarantees the addition and removal are going to happen.

Comment: " For that reason, you wouldn't want a singleton pattern, just a MonoBehaviour implementation with a call to DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject) (if you want it to persist across scenes)." - One does not omit the other, the Singleton is quick to call. instead of having to search through GameObjects to find the SaveManager.

Comment: Your solution prevents the need for searching through GameObjects and that works; I think I just worded that particular comment of mine poorly. What you would have is not a singleton, it is just a global reference; the difference being a singleton implementation _enforces that only one object of its type can ever be instantiated_. What you have isn't wrong (and I gave you a +1 because it certainly helps OP). What I meant to say was that if you used a `MonoBehaviour` _with that particular code_, it wouldn't be a "singleton."  You'll have a static reference to the first one that calls Awake()

Comment: That is correct. He could make it into a non-Monobehaviour for a normal Singleton to be possible. I'd say the approach in the script above is the closest a Monobehaviour can get to a Singleton as it, to my knowledge, always is attachable to new objects.

Comment: This answer is unfortunately plain wrong in Unity (and, simply, does not work at all) for the many reasons explained.  There are no "singletons" in an ECS system .. a unity scene is nothing more than exactly like using photoshop. In photoshop you have a bit of paper, with marks on it. It is meaningless to think of singletons or any other OO concepts.  In Unity you have a scene ("a 3D space") with "game objects" in it. It is meaningless to think of singletons or any other OO concepts.

Comment: The term "Singleton" may not be used, nonetheless the solution will work due to the Awake method being called before the Start method in the Unity lifecycle. Alternatively he could make a utility class that isn't a monobehaviour but does have a constructor and could be set as a Singleton if he wants. Furthermore the "DontDestroyOnLoad" function would allow for retaining the Monobehaviour awake/start savemanager in my solution, if he wants it to stay intact across scenes. I see no reason why the above solution should not work.

Comment: Actually you don't need that manager/Singleton thingy **at all** ;) See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65495834/7111561)

Comment: Well they're different approaches. Still works.

Comment: This works, until you need to interact with the interface at edit time. At edit time, the method Start() will not be executed unless you specifically add an attribute to make a class runnable at edit time, which I won't do it so nilly-willy as it's expensive.
But I won't downvote this as accessing at run time only is mostly what you actually want.

Comment: For edit time you may be able to use this method: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html

Answer (score 3):

## The typical real-world solution:

```
using System.Linq;

public interface Automateme
{
    public void Automate();
}
```

then ...

```
void _do()
{
    Automateme[] aa = GameObject
    .FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>()
    .OfType<Automateme>()
    .Where(a => ((MonoBehaviour)a).enabled)
    .ToArray<Automateme>();

    if (aa.Length == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Automator .. none");
        return;
    }
    Debug.Log($"Automator .. " + aa.Length);

    foreach (Automateme a in aa)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Automator {a.GetType()} {((MonoBehaviour)a).gameObject.name}");
    }

    // do something to one of them randomly, for example! ->
    aa.AnyOne().Automate();
}
```

One point, it is all-but inevitable that you will need the object also as a MonoBehavior, so it's sensible (and no less/more inefficient) to use the `FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>()` idea first mentioned by @derHugo

Some points

- Of course, obviously, in some situations **you wouldn't at all do what is asked in this question**, you'd trivially "keep a list" of the items under consideration. (And that would vary greatly depending on the situation, do you only want active ones, do you want to include items on their first frame of bringup, etc etc etc). The entire point of the question is for the (many, typical) situations where you want to get them on the fly and caching is not relevant
- Unity development, confusingly, **has a massive, just ridiculously big, domain range**. Many types of projects have perhaps a dozen game objects in the whole scene; other types of projects can have 10,000 game objects in the scene. Games with 2D physics are incredibly different from games with 3D physics, rendering approaches are incredibly different from shader approaches, and so on. Naturally with any "style" question like this if you are coming from a certain "domain" in your head, the answer can be quite different.
- Regarding FindObjectsOfType and similar calls, it's worth remembering that **Unity efficiency has incredibly moved on from the early days**. It used to be that the "first thing you'd tell new Unity programmers" was "Don't do something every frame that searches the scene!!! OMG! You'll slow down to 1fps!"  *Of course* that is still true in certain, perhaps many, domains.  BUT it is (for a decade now) often just *completely wrong*.  Unity's caching and handling of scene objects is now blisteringly fast (you can't write faster) and - as mentioned in the previous point - you're often just talking about a handful of items anyways. {A good example of the change in efficiency of the entire Unity paradigm is "pooling". (Any game programmers not as old as me can look up what that was :) )  In the early days of Unity you'd Pool! everything in a panic, My God, I may have *three* tanks at once, get a pooling library! Indeed I am so old I wrote one of the first popular Pooling articles that everyone used for awhile (long since deleted). Nowadays Unity's handling of instantiating prefabs or offscreen models is so fast and clever that you could more or less say they offer pooling built-in, and nowadays there's no need at all to pool things like everyday bullets from machine guns, etc. Anyway the point of this example is just that the (very old) "standard advice" about not searching the scene has to be understood more completely, these days.}

Swinging back to the original question:

> I don't want to search for each Monobehaviour in the scene and then try to get its interface component.

The only way in a game engine to search each object in a scene, is to search each object in the scene. So there's no way around that.  Of course, one can "keep a list" BUT it rather misses the two points (A) in some/many situations that's just not viable/sensible in a game architecture and (B) Unity *is already* incredibly good at keeping a list of game objects / components, it's the whole raison d'etre of a frame engine.  (Note that if it's a physics game, the whole PhysX system for goodness sake is doing an astounding, cutting-edge job, of "finding things every frame", using mathematically freaky spatial hashing and more, dealing with orders of complexity that go with the square or worse of every physics poly in the scene! Compared to that it is misguided to worry about you pulling out 3 items from a list of 50 (which are flawlessly hashed and managed for efficiency by the frame engine anyway).)

Comment: just remember to add using System.Linq;
in your file, and his code works

Comment: good one, added !

Answer (score 1):

How about having global state, perhaps an list of `ISaveable`, and have each savable object add a reference to it during `start()`?  Then you can simply iterate through the array, invoking `SaveData()` on each `ISaveable` reference?

Comment: This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49330090/7111561) answer but would require to explicitly implement that method in all implementations of the interface...

Comment: There could be an abstract class implementing the ISaveable with add/remove functionalities to a static list of ISaveable. Then, sub classes inherits from that abstrac and it's only done once for all with ability to override if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this solution is highly inefficient, but you could use LINQ to filter out the components that implement your interface. In this case `MyInterface` is the interface that we want to query for.

```cs
MyInterface[] myInterfaces = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>()
    .OfType<MyInterface>()
    .ToArray();
```

Small note to clarify "inefficient": With Unity optimizing their object querying methods the call is not even that bad. The issue is that LINQ allocates a lot of GC, which could introduce frame drops, which is why you should *never* run these "heavy" operations on a per-frame basis.

Running the query upon startup or when doing an obvious intensive operation (saving/loading) is totally fine.

Comment: It's worth noting it's not *that* inefficient.  (A) in many situations there are not actually that many objects in a scene. (Unity is confusing like that: domains can vary GREATLY. You can have 1000s of objects in some game paradigms, and only a handful in others.)  (B) Unity's hashing to game objects is nowadays blazing fast.  (C) Don't forget the general beginner's warning in Unity *"Don't search the whole scene every frame!"* only applies to "in every frame".There's no problem at all if once every few minutes or such you have to "search whole scene". This is the solution *in many cases*.

Comment: @Fattie you're right! The current phrasing makes it sound like it's unviable, which is not the case. Do note that the answer is more than two years old, Unity has done a lot of optimization on the primitive operations such as component or object querying. The main takeaway point from the inefficiency comment was that you should **not** run this operation every frame, which goes for **any** large-scale operation. Caching results is the way to go. I use this approach of finding objects often in projects inside `Start` or `Awake`, and in most cases it's not even noticable.

Comment: For sure!  By the way, I took the liberty of adding another example to your great answer.  Obviously on this site just undo, delete etc any edits you don't like!!  Cheers!!  bounty en route

Comment: I appreciate your initiative, but I rolled back the changes. While the code was fine, it seems rather redundant, since it's just the code example I gave with additional boilerplate code applied. I did however, thanks to your suggestions, clarify on the inefficiency aspects and the task of the code!

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65495834/7111561) for a simpler usage of linq ;)

Comment: Your last edit basically turned your answer in an exact copy of what I proposed in mine ...

Comment: Ah, I assumed you posted the comment as a request to edit the code @derHugo. I can remove it again, if you like. Edit: I'm not really sure why you are going over all the answers, necroing this question, promoting your own answer. Most of these are two years old, and yes, while they can be _improved_, they definitely are valid answers in itself.

Comment: Just for anyone googling here, setting aside idiom, having "MonoBehavior" up front in the filter chain is often convenient, because then you know for sure they are scripts and not components - just FWIW

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improve of your method to get all the MonoBehavior wiht your interface actually in your scenes.

```
void Start()
{
    var myInterface = typeof(MyInterface);
    var monoBehavior = typeof(MonoBehaviour);
    var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(p => myInterface.IsAssignableFrom(p) && monoBehavior.IsAssignableFrom(p));

    var myInstance = new List<MyInterface>();

    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        myInstance.AddRange(FindObjectsOfType(type).Select(x => x as MyInterface));
    }
}
```

Here you don't go through all the GameObject in the scenes, but you do more FindObjectsOfType call, + you have to cast. But no more GetComponent needed.

So depend on your case, but if you put the reflection part in cache (during a loading moment) it can avoid you to implement the Manager pattern and you can keep your interface architecture.

Otherwise you can take a look at the observer pattern, it is a different way to manage call over different class type. https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer

Comment: Is this really more optimized then the [OfType approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65495834/7111561)? ;)

Comment: Probably even, it very depend on how large is your scene, more it is more the Linq approach is bad

Comment: Why would that be? Either way you are using the exact same `FindObjectsOfType` with multiple types .. maybe even more expensive ;) and might get worse with many types implementing the interface

Comment: Because you increase the number of casting. The OfType of Linq function try to cast all the mono in your scene to select the ones that implement the interface. So more you have mono in your scene more you do this operation for nothing.

Comment: I think it's a very interesting thing to use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() - I didn't even know about it :pp whaa.  BTW @FlavienMarianacci there is a typical mistake made by "experienced top programmers who are new to Unity" ...  as you say "during a loading moment " ...  what you do here (often) will not work in "Start".  Recall that annoyingly, all the "Starts" in a scene (at a given moment) are executed in some (more or less random) order.  In any non-trivial game it's common that many of the components are only added dynamically by your code as it goes along.  If the starts happen to..

Comment: .. randomly be in the "wrong order" your plan as presented will not work.  (One of the most annoying bugs in Unity for those new to Unity!)  If you did do something like this, you would have to call for the cache to be made as in your code, manually at a time you know it is appropriate

Comment: Beyond that, note that in general it is extremely unlikely you would want an approach which caches all the items of interest at bringup time.  Almost all game scenes are totally dynamic and you want all the interfaces to "Tanks or Death Rays" *at a given moment* ... in almost all games tanks and death rays come and go as the game progresses!  So inevitably you want an on-the-fly solution, not one cached at bringup time...

Comment: (Just for completeness, a further subtle there is that often you want specifically only Active game objects; indeed on the other hand sometimes you want active+inactive, or only active-in-heirarchy, or whatever...)

Comment: Indeed this is just an other way to answer the main question. And I agree with you, FindObjectOfType is not the good way to manage this

Comment: Regarding the sentence at the end of this answer, which suggest "or just use the observor pattern".  IE, "keep a list of the items".  It's worth remembering that *the entire guts of a game engine* is nothing more than a fat-ass observor pattern with a lot of decoration  :)   Of course, obviously, *in contrast to the very point of this question* you could keep a list.  For example I might ask a question about NOT using PhysX in some specific situation, and there could be various answers, and at the end one could say "oh or use PhysX!" ...

Comment: Hence, to simply repeat my comment under IanH's answer:  It's worth noting it's NOT that inefficient. (A) in MANY OR MOST scene situations there are NOT actually that many objects in a scene. (Unity is confusing like that: domains can vary GREATLY. You can have 1000s of objects in some game paradigms, and only a handful in others.) (B) Unity's hashing to game objects is nowadays blazing fast.....

Comment: @Fattie I put it on a Start for the exemple. I was talking about put it in cache the list of types given by reflection. Ofc getting the instances is to do only on the fly when you need it :)

Comment: ...  (C) Don't forget the general beginner's warning in Unity "Don't search the whole scene every frame!" only applies to "in every frame".There's no problem at all if once every few minutes or such you have to "search whole scene". This is the solution in many cases.

Comment: @FlavienMarianacci , sure, I realize you put in in Start as an example.  However, I'm afraid it is simply "wrong" - any experienced Unity programmer is aware of the endless nuisance where script execution order (either in awake, start or each frame) can catch you out.  "You can't reliably do bring-up stuff in Start" is just a basic in Unity  (of course, obviously, in many simple, hello-world situations it is fine!)

Comment: @Fattie thanks for the different advice, glad if you discover an other way to get types ;)

Comment: @Fattie I would not say that the `Start` is an issue in this answer ... all of the answers here, as well as OP's approach will require to be called at some point like e.g. in `Start` or in a repeated manner ;) (except the manager and list thingy approach)

Comment: hola, Hmm, the OP's example is not in start; nor should this one be!

Comment: @Fattie well it has to be called somewhere ;) `Start` is a valid example .. if you spawn stuff in `Start` it's your fault :D .. should be done in `Awake` ^^

Comment: @FlavienMarianacci I find your solution fancy ;) Note though that have some concerns: What if there are multiple Assemblies and the types spread among them? Or what if I have e.g. an SDK assembly with the interface and this code shall be run in this SDK assembly which doesn't know the types actually implementing the interface? Also you'll have to filter again .. currently I guess you would get the same reference twice if it has some derived type like e.g. `public class SomeSaveable : BaseSaveable{} public class BaseSaveable : ISaveable{}` you will get it for both `FindObjectsOfType`

Comment: And finally again: Is it more performant to iterate **once** through 100 components and try to cast them or to iterate through 100 components for each type that implements the interface and try to find components that implement that type or a derived one? ;)

Comment: @derHugo for all the questions : additionnal filtering method or pretreatment can be done to solve this. But you right my solution is more complex so it will generate more bugs and complexity. So we dont met the famous KISS.

Comment: @derHugo on your last comment, in my solution I dont iterate through 100 components for each type. Read it again I iterate over only the one that have the good interface. if you have 1000 component for 100 that have the interface, you will try to cast 900 for nothing, where i will cast only the 100 goods. Even if the 100 goods are split over 3 types

Comment: @FlavienMarianacci what do you think `FindObjectsOfType` does internally? It somehow has to go over all GameObjects in the scene and check if any of their components implements the type (or a derived type) you are passing in as parameter. So anyway it is trying to cast or at least check if it could be cast to the target type :) e.g. if you use `FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Renderer))` you will get all instances of type `MeshRenderer`, `LineRenderer`, `SkinnedMeshRenderer` etc .. then you do `FindObjectsOfType(typeof(MeshRenderer))` and go over all scene objects again in order to find these etc

Comment: You got a point there, Im not sure how Unity is doing. For sure it is more fast than when we do that by ourselves. Because it probably do the hard part in the C++ and probably use less memory allocation. But it worth a benchmark

Answer (score -1):

In my case I was using this implementation:

```
    MonoBehaviour[] saveableScripts = (MonoBehaviour[])FindObjectsOfType(typeof(MonoBehaviour));
    foreach (var enemy in saveableScripts)
    {
        if (enemy is ISaveable == false)
            continue;

        // you code ...
        saveables.Add(currentComponent);
    }
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65495834/7111561) for basically doing the same in a single line ;)

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the idea of using an `ISaveable` manager for this use case, as Doh09 and others suggest. But to answer your question as asked, you could traverse the entire scene hierarchy, or multiple scenes' hierarchies, as follows:

```
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<ISaveable> saveables;
    void RefreshSaveables()
    {
        saveables = new List<ISaveable>();
        for (var i = 0; i < SceneManager.sceneCount; ++i)
        {
            var roots = SceneManager.GetSceneAt(i).GetRootGameObjects();
            for (var j = 0; j < roots.Length; ++j)
            {
                saveables.AddRange(roots[j].GetComponentsInChildren<ISaveable>());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The advantage of this over your original code is that you don't need to save every MonoBehaviour in the scene in order to later filter it - however I still think it is preferable for each ISaveable to register itself on `Start` and let the manager call their `Save` methods.

Comment: So why would you then introduce a manager class again? And how is this answer much different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65495834/7111561) .. except it erases the advantage of finding disabled or inactive components ...

Comment: This is completely wrong in Unity (or any game engine, any ECS system) for the reasons I explain in the long comments under FlavienMarianacci answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can improve the code by replacing

```cs
ISaveable currentComponent = currentObj.GetComponent<ISaveable>();
```

with

```cs
ISaveable currentComponent = currentObj as ISaveable;
```

Answer (score -2):

One way is to use unity container (though slightly older way). Register all the dependencies to container through configuration. All the instances of the ISaveable can be registered to unit container and then resolve them in the code

example:

unity container in web.config:

```
<container name=“GameObjectContainer”>
    <register type=“ISaveable” mapTo=“Example1” />
    <register type=“ISaveable” mapTo=“Example2” />
</container>
```

ISavable definition:

```
public interface ISavable
{
    void SaveData();
}
```

ISavable implementation:

```
public class Example1 : ISavable
{
    public void SaveData()
    {
    }
}

public class Example2 : ISavable
{
    public void SaveData()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Note though that `UnityContainer` != [`Unity3D`](https://unity.com) ;)