# How to find not active objects from the scene by the C# script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a several objects and want to put them into massive. I want to method or something another like a `FindGameObjectsByTag()`, but for the not active objects.

I said, I tried `FindGameObjectsByTag()`, but actually works only for active objects.

Comment: no but if you looked around a bit more you would find https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll.html - where you can find all objects and take from it only the ones which are inactive  - may not seem efficient, but thats the price of inactive unmonitored objects.

Comment: There is nothing for tags ... you can go by type and use [`FindObjectsByType<T>(true)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) which will include inactive objects and instead of a tag simply use a dedicated component instead. Alternative would be to indeed iterate through all objects and find tagged ones manually similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49329764/get-all-components-with-a-specific-interface-in-unity)

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the game object is active in the hierarchy by using
object.activeInHierarchy;
it returns a true or false answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).